# Way to determine if X and Y are both over 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if there was a way of telling if two numbers were both above 0. I was thinking of using an `elif` statement but I wasn't sure if that would work.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant if both were over 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [boolean operators](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) to test more than one condition, here the `and` operator does what you want:

```
if x > 0 and y > 0:
    # x and y are both over 0.
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here's another method:

```
if min(x, y) > 0:
    # x any y are both over 0
```

Comment: This is probably best if there are more than two items to check.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: true, if there are several values to test and they all have to be over 0, `min()` might be an option.

Comment: Just to be clear: I'd accept Martijn's answer, I've added this for fun (as mentioned in the answer itself).

Comment: Thanks for this! I might look into this if I ever want to vary my coding a bit.

Comment: ...come to think of it, if there are more than two items to check, something like `if all(i > 0 for i in (x, y, z))` will probably be even better...